# Why is my forms textboxes auto filling with previous textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, textbox

I have a drupal 7 site and recently i have noticed something with with text forms. Say i have a form with 4 textboxes. I fill the first one with a value say "John". If i click or tab through the next few textboxes, if i don't fill them out they get auto filled with "John". If i go and try to clear them, and i click outside the box or 'Tab' out of the box it gets filled in again with the value i just cleared. Does anyone know what would be causing this? I am guessing that there may be a .blur() somewhere that is doing this but i don't know where that is. I tried $('.form-text').unbind('blur'); but its still happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

Comment: If in chrome, Inspect element & go to Sources tab. Find the script & look through the events..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is causing the auto fill but I had a similar issue in the past and found adding  autocomplete="off" to the html on the tag fixed the problem for me.  Hopefully it will help.